# React.useMemo does not work to prevent re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following simple component:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [{ data, loading, hasError, errors }] = useApiCall(true)

  if (hasError) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ActivityFeedTitle>
      <ActivityFeed data={data} isLoading={loading} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

I would like to prevent ALL re-renders of the `ActivityFeedTitle` component, so that it only renders once, on load. My understanding is that I should be able to use the `React.useMemo` hook with an empty dependencies array to achieve this. I changed by `return` to be:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        {React.useMemo(() => <ActivityFeedTitle>, [])}
        <ActivityFeed data={data} isLoading={loading} />
    </Fragment>
)
```

As far as I'm concerned, this should prevent all re-renders of that component? However, the `ActivityFeedTitle` component still re-renders on every render of the `Dashboard` component.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Using `React.memo` still causes the same issue. I tried memoizing my `ActivityFeedTitle` component as follows:

```
const Memo = React.memo(() => (
  <ActivityFeedTitle />
))
```

And then used it like this in my return:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        {<Memo />}
        <ActivityFeed data={data} isLoading={loading} />
    </Fragment>
)
```

Same problem occurs. I also tried passing in `() => false` the following as the second argument of `React.memo`, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) instead to memoized components based on props.

```
React.memo(function ActivityFeedTitle(props) {
  return <span>{props.title}</span>
})
```

Take note:

> This method only exists as a **performance optimization**. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've also tried solving this with `React.memo`, but I run into the same problem. See my latest edit to OP. Is it because my component has no props?

Comment: `ActivityFeed` is a function component, is there any other workaround for FC's?

Comment: @JavascriptLoser so how did you verify it was not optimized? See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use React.memo and use it where your define your component not where you are making an instance of the component, You can do this in your ActivityFeedTitle component as

```
const ActivityFeedTitle = React.memo(() => {
  return (
   //your return
  )
})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The second argument passed to `React.memo` would need to return `true` in order to prevent a re-render. Rather than computing whether the component should update, it's determining whether the props being passed are equal.

Comment: Where is the example?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `useMemo` is incorrect.

From react hooks doc:

> Pass a “create” function and an array of dependencies. useMemo will
>   only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has
>   changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on
>   every render.
>
> If no array is provided, a new value will be computed on every render.

You need to use `useMemo` like `useEffect` here for computation of value rather than rendering the component.

**`React.memo`**

`React.memo()` is the one you are looking for. It prevents re-rendering unless the props change.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've also tried solving this with `React.memo`, but I run into the same problem. See my latest edit to OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's because rendering a parent causes it's children to re-render for the most part.  The better optimization here would be to place your data fetching logic either in the ActivityFeed component or into a HOC that you wrap ActivityFeed in.